# Stack and Heap locations in RAM

Tags: memory-management

[image: What happens in the middle?]
This image and others like it have been bothering me for a while now. When I use `malloc`, this should be a part of the dynamic data, the heap. However, this seems to be bounded from above by the stack, which seems very ineffective. A program cannot predict how much memory I plan on allocating, so how does the program judge how far up to put the stack? It seems as though all of the memory in the middle is wasted, and I would like to know how this works for programs that could potentially range from a small service program that doesn't use any dynamic memory verses a videogame that could potentially allocate huge sections of memory.

Say, for example, I open up Microsoft paint. If I paste a high resolution picture into it, the memory allocation of paint skyrockets. Where was this memory taken from? What I would truly like is a snapshot of my entire RAM stick labelled as above to visualize how the many programs of a computer partition the computer's memory as a whole, but I can only find diagrams like this one for a single process and a single section of RAM.

Comment: How far up ? All the way. Place it at the top of the memoryto maximize available memory(or rather; address space)   - which is what quite a lot of operating system does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: @JanSchultke That's a much broader question with much broader answers, mine is a specific question ("Why wasting space in the middle?"), which Basile Starynkevitch answered insanely beautifully almost a decade ago.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your picture is not of the RAM, but of the [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) of some [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). The [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29) configures the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) to manage virtual memory, provide the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of a process, and do some [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), and manage the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

BTW, it is not the compiler which grows the stack (so your picture is wrong). The compiler is generating machine code which may push or pop things on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). For [`malloc` allocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) heap, the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementation contains the `malloc` function, above [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) primitives or [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) allocating [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29) of virtual memory (e.g. [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on Linux).

On [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), a process can ask its address space to be changed with [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) -and `munmap` and `mprotect`. When a program is started with [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) the kernel is setting its initial address space. See also `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and try `cat /proc/$$/maps`....). BTW `mmap` is often  used to implement [malloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) -runtime loading of [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)),  both heavily used in the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project (it is a free software artificial intelligence project for Linux).

Since most Linux systems are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source), I suggest you to dive into implementation details by downloading then looking inside the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/): both implement `malloc` and `dlopen` above `mmap` and other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

<sup>Windows has similar facilities, but I don't know Windows. Refer to the documentation of the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)</sup>

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/), and, if you code in C, some good book such as [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website. Be sure to read the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). See also the [OSDEV](https://www.osdev.org/) website.

Be aware that modern C compilers are permitted to make extensive [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). Read [*what every C programmer should know about undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). See also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report.

Comment: Thank you, after looking through those articles a lot of my questions have been resolved and I plan on researching into virtual memory space more. In fact, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space#/media/File:Virtual_address_space_and_physical_address_space_relationship.svg) diagram made me feel much better about how physical address space is partitioned.

Comment: As for the compiler, I believe the person who made that diagram was referring to the fact that the compiler created the code that managed the stack, not that the compiler did anything at runtime. The idea that the programmer manages the heap is just as incorrect from that point of view, because the programmer doesn't actively control the heap, the executable instructions control it (the blue at the bottom).

Comment: When you said _"... For `malloc`-allocated **heap**, the C standard library implementation contains the `malloc` function, above operating system primitives or system calls allocating pages of virtual memory..."._ What about the **stack**? When a computer program pushes or pops a stack frame from the **call stack** (e.g. calling or returning from a subroutine), does the program's compiled code reference (paginated) **virtual memory addresses**? And if so, I'd imagine those pages are already _allocated_ ahead of time, or is that not always the case?

Comment: @Josh The program refers to the stack in a relative way. For example it says this local variable is stored in current value of stack pointer + 2. It never says this local variable should be stored in 0x00000111 of virtual memory.

Answer (score 1):

In modern systems, a technique called virtual memory is used to give the program its own memory space. Heap and stack locations are at specific locations in virtual memory. The kernel then takes care of mapping memory locations between physical memory and virtual memory. Your program may have a chunk of memory allocated at 0x80000000, but that chunk of memory might be stored in location 0x49BA5400. Your actual RAM stick would be a jumbled mess of chunks of all of those sections in seemingly random locations.